# failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)

Tags: arch-linux

I'm trying to update my Arch but I get this error:

```
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing libvpx (1.13.0-1) breaks dependency 'libvpx.so=7-64' required by ffmpeg-compat-57
```

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Welcome to U&L. As a new member of the community it's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how the sites work. You'll find for example advice on [how to formulate a clear, easily answerable question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) etc. Generally in this kind of situation you should include the exact commands you give and complete outputs enclosed in the code brackets `{ }` to preserve the formatting. OS version etc. are also important details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means exactly what it says.  Package `ffmpeg-compat-57` depends on version 7-64 of `libvpx.so`, but you are trying to install a different version of libvpx (1.13.0-1) which doesn't satisfy that dependency.

This is not unusual - `ffmpeg` has always been finicky about dependencies, generally requiring **exact** matches with library versions so as to avoid breakage due to incompatibilities.

You need to either:

1. Upgrade ffmpeg-compat to a version that works with libvpx 1.13.0-1

   I don't know the exact details of the arch repo you're using, but this may be as simple as waiting a few days for a new version to be uploaded, or for the mirror you are using to catch up.

or

2. Don't upgrade libvpx

or

3. Figure out whether you even need to have `ffmpeg-compat-57` installed.  It's only a compatibility package to provide older versions of libavcodec and related libraries.  If you don't use any software that requires those old versions, you should be able to safely remove it.